# How to separate long text data of cell into two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have **Name** and **Address** two details in one cell:

```
NKG JAYANTI COFFEE PVT. LTD. 501 QUEENS CORNER, "A" 3 QUEENS ROAD, BANGALORE -560 001.KARNATAKA STATE. 

ALLANASONS LIMITED, CHANCO RESIDENCY NO.1/2 SRT LANE CUNNINGHAM ROAD CROSS BANGALORE-560 052, KARNATAKA.
```

Please tell me how I can separate this data from one cell.

Comment: I'd do it using regular expressions (there are free add-ins for Excel), but I can't give more specific answer without knowing how it's possible to split the two fields.

Comment: You may get better answers if you describe how you want Excel to distinguish between the name and the address; i.e., tell where the name ends and the address begins.  Is it the first comma?  The last comma?  The first number?

Answer (score 1):

In Column B next to A:   `=left($A2,FIND(",", $A2,1)-1)`
In Column C next to B:   `=mid($A2,FIND(",", $A2,1)+2,len($A2)-len($B2))`

will give you answers:

After entering the formulas, you pull the fill-in handle and drag the columns B and C down, until last line of data. Also if you want the data to be the real text part of the string in A1 then you have to copy the whole column B and C and Past Special them in a empty area on your sheet. Now they are text and the old B and C can be deleted.

Comment: As long as you are breaking `A2` into only two pieces (rather than, for example, name / street address / city), you can simplify your second formula to `=RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)-FIND(",", A2)-1)`